# Conditional Logic in django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, conditional-statements, branch

I'm trying to build a conditional form where selecting one option will cause a new field to appear underneath, while selecting another option will display something else.

Formstack has a good example https://www.formstack.com/features/conditional-logic

I couldn't find any preexisting form packages for django with this functionality. How should I start implementing this?

Comment: Make the fields optional and then use `javascript` to render your fields based on change event of the referred field.

Comment: Could I then use django's backend to administer the fields?

Comment: Yes, of course. just make sure you have the name of the fields right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django forms (especially if you use the `ModelForm` library) are a direct reflection of your Django application `Model`. You should therefore start by refactoring your Django application `Model` to have fields that have optional values (i.e. they can be `NULL`, `empty` or have a `default` value already created).

These would be the form fields that are shown/hidden based on your conditional(s) and they may or may not have values (if they are hidden based on a conditional it is impossible to provide a value to them so the `Model` fields must be able to accept `NULL` values or use the defaults).

You would then use a client-side language such as Javascript (JS) to handle the user iteraction with your Django application. A simple to use JS framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) would be worthwhile investigating for your needs.

In addition to the exceptional [Django docs on Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/), I also highly recommend you take a look at [Django Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) writtten by PyDanny to see how Django forms should be done right.